# Blank ListView when calling Invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, class, listview

`listView` is owned by the class `Form1`. The subroutine `anotherThread` in a separate class transmission is started in a thread by a subroutine in `Form1`. `Form1` owns another public subroutine `addItemsListView`, which uses `Invoke`.
When `transmission.anotherThread` calls `addItemsListView`, the subroutine runs, but `listView` remains blank.

Have tried delegates, invokes etc. inside each class but the same problem.

```
Class Form1
    Property myTransmission = New transmission
    Private Sub aSubRoutine() Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(
            Sub()
                myTransmission.anotherThread()
            End Sub
        )
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub addItemsListView(ByVal items As String())
        If listView.InvokeRequired Then
            listView.Invoke(Sub() addItemsListView(items))
        Else
            For each item In Items
                listView.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Class transmission
    Public Sub anotherThread()
        Form1.addItemsListView(New String() {"abc", "def"})
    End Sub
End Class
```

So I expect "abc" and "def" to be in the `listView` but it remains completely blank. If I step through the code, however, everything seems to be running smoothly.

Comment: In `Form1.addItemsListView` ... Form1 is not the instance, rather the vb.net default form instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't talking to your existing form.  Pass it as a reference:

```
Public Sub anotherThread(inForm As Form1)
  inForm.addItemsListView(New String() {"abc", "def"})
End Sub
```

then include your form when you call it:

```
myTransmission.anotherThread(Me)
```

Comment: @Mr_Random_Guy Guessing: add two columns to your ListView then.

Comment: @Mr_Random_Guy This is a different issue than what you asked.  I used your code and added a ListView with two columns and in Details view, made my fixes, and it worked.

Comment: Okay, I'll start a new question.